# Understangin Laurent's Theorem in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Laurent's theorem states that if a complex function $f(z)$ is analytic in an annulus region $D$ bounded by two concentric circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ with cetntre $z_0$ and radii $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ ($\rho_1 >\rho_2)$ and $z$ is any point in $D$ then

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n(z-z_0)^{-n}$$ Where

$$a_n=\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_1}\frac {f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$ and $$b_n=\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_2}{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n-1}dz}$$

So does than mean that always $b_n=a_{-n}$ ?

I am asking this question in context of this explaination given in solution for the question

Expand $$f(z)=\sin{c(1+{1\over z})}$$, and the solution says this

[image]

why have they written that $b_n=a_{-n}$ as $f(z)=f({1\over z}$ ? Why is this comparison needed ?

and in yet another question

[image]

Comment: @Surb : yeah, i have updated the question to include the context in which i am asking. may be this would help explain better

Comment: I updated my answer too :). I think it is answering your question.

Comment: The point is that here $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = f(z)$, and that gives a symmetry in the Laurent coefficients, like evenness ($g(-z) = g(z)$) introduces a "symmetry" in the coefficients of the MacLaurin series (all odd coefficients are $0$).

Comment: @DanielFischer But why is this comparison needed to show $b_n=a_{-n}$ ? I still dont get the relation

Comment: It's like a Fourier series, $$g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx}.$$ If $g$ is even, then you have $c_{-n} = c_n$, and if $g$ is odd, you have $c_{-n} = -c_n$. If we here write the Laurent series as a single series $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_nz^n,$$ then the symmetry of $f$ gives the result $c_{-n} = c_n$, which, in the split form of the Laurent series used here, is $b_n = a_n$. Note that the author got him/herself confused by the splitting, writing $b_n = a_{-n}$, but the indices of $b_k$ resp $a_k$ are _never_ negative, so $b_n = a_{-n}$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, that explains it. In the second page i have uploaded, it says $b_n=(-1)^na_n$, this also works the same way i guess. just where did the exponent $n$ come from for $-1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

... $a_n$ is only defined for $n \geq 0$ and $b_n$ for $n>1$... But yes you could write 
$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n(z-z_0)^n$ with $c_n = a_n$ for $n \geq 0$ and $c_n = b_{-n}$ for $n<0$ but the advantage of "separating" the coefficients is that you can indentify the coefficients $a_n$ with the Taylor coefficients.

Comment: you are right, sorry this was a typo... $b_n$ is not consistently defined for negative $n$.

Comment: But why is this comparison $f(z)=f({1\over z})$ needed to show $b_n=a_{-n}$ ? I still dont get the relation

Comment: I think you are mixing the fact that $b_n = a_{-n}$ which is always true by definition and the fact that $b_n = a_n$ which is only true for a certain class of functions.

Answer (score 1):

If

$$a_n=\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_1}\frac {f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$ $$b_n=\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_2}{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n-1}dz}$$

It should be clear that $$a_{-n} = \frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_1}\frac {f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{-n+1}} =\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int_{c_1}f(z){(z-z_0)^{n-1}}dz = b_n$$

I don't like this way of presenting Laurent series so I will link to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) which provides an alternate definition using only one series. I prefer this definition to other ones.

Comment: SO by this definition one needs only to find $a_n$. But in the solution given in the book, why have they written that $b_n=a_{-n}$ as $f(z)=f({1\over z}$ ? Why is this comparison needed ?

Comment: I think the comparison is used to say that $a_n = a_{-n}$ rather than $b_n = a_{-n}$. In essence, we are saying that $b_n$ = $a_n$.

Comment: In the second picture we are saying that $b_n = (-1)^n a_n$.

Comment: Yeah but how did we get $b_n=(-1)^n a_n$ ?